# jquery re-setting/reformat datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i have a form with a datepicker. i want the datepicker setting in each function be different. so i write the script like this:

```
function add(){
    $("#dari").datepicker( {changeMonth: true,
    changeYear : true,
    minDate    : minth+minmo+minda,
    maxDate    : "+1Y",
    dateFormat :"dd-mm-yy"},"showAnim","clip");
}
function edit(){
    $("#dari").datepicker( {changeMonth: true,
     changeYear : true,
     minDate    : minth+minmo+minda,
     maxDate    : "+5Y",
     dateFormat :"dd-mm-yy"},"showAnim","clip");
}
// note : minth, minmo, minda has been defined, there's no problem with them
```

my objective is : 
 when i  call `add()` function, the maximum date of datepicker is 1 year from now. and when i call `edit()` function, the maximum date of datepicker is 5 years from now.
the matter is :
when i call `add()` function first, the maximum date of datepicker is 1 year from now (as i hope), but when i call `edit()` function, the maximum date of it is still 1 year, not 5year. and so if i call `edit()` function first, the maximum date is 5 years, and when i call `add()` function it still 5 years.
can some one tell me what to do? is the datepicker can't be resetted?

Answer (score 0):

How about just calling the option method

```
$( "#dari" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+5y");
```

see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-option

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well.  I mean set all the default values initially, but when you want to use `add` or `edit` the just change the `maxDate` (the only option that changes)

Comment: ah,, i got. did you mean use another function for define maxdate only? i'll try :D